# Dynamics Nav 2015 (Navision) integration

Tags: ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm looking for advise and a strategy for integrating Dynamics Nav 2015 with Craft Commerce.  I realise this is a broad question and a hard one, certainly since Craft Commerce has only been recently released.

One of the most important parts is that the integration from user perspective should be a fluent as possible:

- (Live) Get prices and stock level
- (Live) Get custom prices based on customer group and volume discounts
- (Batch) Get Product catalogue (both products and categories)
- (Batch) Get Product variants
- (Batch) Get all product details (like measurements, custom properties)
- (Live) Post basket to calculate total pricing (based on eg applicable taxes)
- (Live) Post new customers and contacts
- (Live) Get customers and contacts
- (Live) Post new orders
- (Live) Get orders and its details
- (Batch ? Live) Get invoices and its details
- (Live) Get address information (shipping / invoice)
- (Live) Post Address information (shipping / invoice)

Other important parts are:

- How to deal with user accounts: The navision contact on the same level as the user in craft.  But how would you deal with the creation of it, given that a user can created starting from both sides (from the web as a new contact in navision, from navision and later from the web as an existing contact).  All contacts / users need to be linked to a company object in Nav (again already existing in Nav or completely new)
- Would it be possible to use queueing from Craft, to eg store orders that are taken when the Navision is not available.  Same goes for pricing info ,etc

I would be very interested to see

- your general thoughts about the above
- is it doable to have craft commerce that tightly integrated (what are other pitfalls I didn't think about)
- if there is anybody who already started a similar challenge

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have an answer to that but I have exactly the same questions. Craft Commerce would be highly interesting for a client I’m working for, but they have Navision running, too. Without the integration it’s not possible to use Craft. I fiddled around with the plugin architecture, but I never wrote a Craft plugin before, which is why my efforts won’t lead anywhere near a solution.

Comment: Are there any other people interested in this?  I would like to know if there is any traction on this idea?

Comment: Hey Tim. Did you get any response or find out any useful information in regard to Nav integration since you asked the question?

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately not. I find it hard to believe that no one would have ever done a close Integration between craft commerce and navision or another major ERP. The project has been done with custom development, although i am still open to other experiences because i’m still wondering if it is doable.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you didn't end up using Craft Commerce at all?

Comment: no, that's correct other custom development was used.  I do believe Craft is heading more natively in this direction eg GraphQL functionality since the last version but is at this moment still missing create / update recipes.  Still very open to suggestions and best practise in this regards